# I need these buttons to control which div is showing or "on top"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have these buttons on the side of my page, and a main content area taking up the better part of the page.

What I am trying to do is get the button I click to change the main content to a div containing the corresponding information. This is very hard to find, perhaps because I am searching by the wrong terms, and I have covered a good portion of stackoverflow without much luck.

I have though about absolutely positioning the divs and using a script to change the z-index of the the divs to the highest amount using a "=+1" type situation, but I could see that getting messy.

I have considered adapting a script I have that replaces part of an image file name in order to change a main picture on a page to a larger version of the image corresponding to a thumb name, though this script targets file names so it isn't going well.

I have also tried something along the lines of:

"id of button" onclick function = "main content class" change id to "corresponding div"

only in javascript talk, and this isn't working at all so I can only assume that I am either looking at it wrong or I have some messed up in the code.

```
$('#tabhead1').click(function() {
  document.getElementByClassName("maintab").id = "tabs1";
});
```

This is driving me crazy and I would really appreciate some ideas. I tried to leave it free formed so that noone gets hung up on anyone solution.

**** Just to clarify, I have 5 divs id'd at #tabhead1, #tabhead2, #tabhead3, etc. and 5 content divs classed as .maintab, and id'd as tabs1, tabs2, tabs3, etc. I need the first content div to show automatically, and for that div to change based on the button clicked. at the moment all content divs are set to display: none; except the first one.

Comment: post a jsfiddle.net. this is not giving us any clues

Comment: Your mixing jQuery and Javascript syntax. I think you have really overcomplicated your question, do you want to click the button and change content within a div? If so Robs answer will do just that

Comment: I'm sure I have, but this seams really simple for something I'm not able to grasp. I have 5 divs set up as buttons, and I have 5 divs set up with content corresponding to the values of the buttons. they are all set to display: none at the moment except the first one.

Comment: I think it would be much easier for people to grasp if you posted an excerpt of your html.  Anyway, here's an example using show and hide: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/Z5xks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For each button, add a `data` attribute related to the corresponding `<div>`

for example

```
<button id="tabhead1" data-content="tabs1" >first Tab</button>
```

- apply a common class for the tabs, for example `.tab`

Then you can do the following

```
$('button').click(function(){
 var contentId = $(this).data('content'); // get the id of corresponding tab
 $('.tab').hide(); // hide all tabs
 $('#'+contentId).show(); //show the corresponding tab
});
```

Comment: Your brilliant! I added the data-content= to my divs that I'm using as buttoms. I'm not actually using buttons. I was worried that it wouldn't work but sure enough it works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getElementbyClassName` which does not exists. Use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("maintab")[0].id = "tabs1"; 
// Get all elements to match classname + get first element from array
```

And for the rest, I don't know why you want to add id with JS? Why not just add them to your HTML?

Comment: javascript eludes me, I rarely reach the correct conclusion. If I am getting this right, I should have all of my content divs classed as "maintab" and your script would link the first content div, "[0]", to my first button, "#tabs1"? How does the script know that tabs2 belongs to the second content div, etc.?

Comment: You fix one syntax error but not the issue, which is OP is clueless about show and hide. IDs should never be changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#tabhead1').click(function() {
   // get element with class 'maintab' and replace its content with that of another tab
  $(".maintab").html($(".tabs1").html());
});
```

Comment: This the way it is changed the main content to blank. I then realized that ".tabs1" is a class so I changed it to "#tabs1" thinking that this code would target .maintab and give it an id of tabs1, tabs2, tabs3, etc depending on the ('#tabhead-') that the code was targeting. however it only reloaded the pages as if clicking a link set to pound.

Comment: Have a look at this, it might make it clearer.  http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/Ah2TZ/

Comment: Are you including the jQuery library in your page?

Comment: All the content is present. Just hide all and show relevant

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little on the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/Z5xks/)** I posted in the comments earlier:

This uses a method very similar to @tilwin-joy, so I guess we were of like mindedness.  There are a couple of small differences that I would point out:

**jQuery:**

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var button = $(this);
    var target = button.data('target');
    button.prop('disabled', true).siblings().prop('disabled', false);
    $(target).show('slow').siblings().hide();
});
```

1. This uses siblings to hide the other content (one less pass at the DOM).
2. I suggest just setting your data value with the id hash in the markup, I think it's a bit clearer to read and follow (IMHO) in both the script and markup.
3. This script also sets the current button to be disabled when clicked.  The benefit of this is that you can use the disabled property to style up your buttons, and even if you don't style them it gives a visual cue to the user as to which tab content is currently displayed. Check out the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/Z5xks/)** to see how this can be used for styling purposes.

**HTML:**  (I stripped some of the unneeded ids from what you described as your markup).

```
<div class="tabhead">
    <button data-target="#tabs1" disabled="true">Content 1</button>
    <button data-target="#tabs2">Content 2</button>
    <button data-target="#tabs3">Content 3</button>
    <button data-target="#tabs4">Content 4</button>
    <button data-target="#tabs5">Content 5</button>
</div>
<div class="maintab">
    <div id="tabs1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350/e8117f/fff&text=Image+1" alt="Image 1" />
        <p>This is the content of tabs1.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350/9acd32/fff&text=Image+2" alt="Image 2" />
        <p>This is the content of tabs2.</p>        
    </div>
    <div id="tabs3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350/9400d3/fff&text=Image+3" alt="Image 3" />
        <p>This is the content of tabs3.</p>        
    </div>
    <div id="tabs4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350/ffd700/fff&text=Image+4" alt="Image 4" />
        <p>This is the content of tabs4.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs5">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350/1e90ff/fff&text=Image+5" alt="Image 5" />
        <p>This is the content of tabs5.</p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS:**  Not needed - just to give you an idea of how you can style the elements to look like tabs.

```
/*This sets all but the first tab to hidden when the page is loaded*/
.maintab>div:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}


/*The rest is just to style the elements to look like tabs*/
body {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}
.maintab, .tabhead {
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.maintab {
    border: 1px solid #1e90ff;
    border-top: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.tabhead {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1e90ff;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
button {
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-bottom: none;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
button:disabled {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #1e90ff;
    color: #1e90ff;
    top: 3px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    z-index: 10;
}
```